# How to add a column in pandas with the value depending on the date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am trying to digitise my portfolio. I have a `dataframe` with the daily stock closing information since a certain period `(01-01-2020)` and I want to add a column showing how many of the stocks I am holding, so for example on `01-01-2020`,  I have zero APPL and from `25-06-2020` I have 2 and from `01-09-2021` I have 1.

I have another `dataframe` that keeps track of the balance of my stocks when it changes (but not the dates in between). This looks like this for this example;

```
Date        Balance
25-06-2020  2
01-09-2021  1
```

I know that
`df['balance'] = 0` will add a column that is all zero but how can I add conditions based on the date?

In summary, I have this

```
Date        Price 
01-01-2020  $100
01-02-2020  $100
...
25-06-2020  $120
26-06-2020  $130
...
01-09-2021  $145
02-09-2021  $146
```

and I want to get to this

```
Date        Price  Balance
01-01-2020  $100   0
01-02-2020  $100   0
...
25-06-2020  $120   2
26-06-2020  $130   2
...
01-09-2021  $145   1
02-09-2021  $146   1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible specify first values of `Balance` in dictionary is possible use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with forward filling missing values:

```
d = {'01-01-2020':0,'25-06-2020':2,'01-09-2021':1}

df['Balance'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').map(d).ffill().astype(int)
```

EDIT: Use left join for new column `Balance`, then forward filling values after `df1['Date']`, first replace by `0`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])

df2 = df.merge(df1[['Date','Balance']], on='Date', how='left')
df2['Balance'] = df2['Balance'].ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Comment: That would work if I only had three dates to add, but I have some stocks where the balance changes much more often

Comment: @user1234 - hmm, can you explain more how and when are `Balance` change?

Comment: As in everytime I bought or sold some stocks, my total balance of the stock changes. So one day I could be holding 100 shares and a week later 20 and another week later 250

Comment: @user1234 - how is count it? From sample data not clear for me.

Comment: @user1234 - Answer was edited.